# Selecting an image at random in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, random, webbrowser-control

I would like to select an image at random from my webbrowser control. 
BTW my next step is to add a "onclick" event to the randomly selected image.

Random Rand = new Random();

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        ArrayList al;
        HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("IMG");
        al = new ArrayList();
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            al.Add(elem.GetAttribute("name"));
            var randImg = Rand[elems.Next(al.Length)];
            // This line gives error please help
        }
        foreach (String s in al)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
    }
}
```

So say I am on this [page](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=799&q=stack&oq=stack&gs_l=img.3..0l10.601.1465.0.2054.5.5.0.0.0.0.280.563.0j2j1.3.0.msedrc...0...1ac.1.58.img..2.3.562.43rTMThXf7Q))

How would I get a random image from this page? My code is above. Am I on the right track?

Comment: check my solution and tell me if helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is only for one image ! Here is the code.

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
            {
                  MessageBox.Show("No document in web browser");
                  return;
            }


            HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("IMG");

            if(elems.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no images on the page");
                return;
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            int randomIndex = r.Next(0, elems.Count-1);

            MessageBox.Show(elems[randomIndex].GetAttribute("name"));

        }
```

Here this should work. You want random image, you should select random number between `0` and `elems.Count- 1`. After that getting this element and his name attribute ! I refactor your code a little bit.

Comment: @ mybirthname - what is elms?

Comment: @Serial_Coder it is typo, now it is fix it should be elems

Comment: @ mybirthname I get the red squigly line under .GetAttribute it says HtmlElement does't contain a definition for .GetAttribute --

Comment: @Serial_Coder man again Typo it is GetAttribute, I wrote it with one t in the answer ! Now it is fixed. Please fix typos by yourself :)

Comment: @ mybirthname what If I want to attach an event handler to that random image?

Comment: @Serial_Coder you can't attach event handler to image from another website. Also do you understand the code atleast :)

Comment: @ mybirthname Why do I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException if I use a different URL?

Comment: @Serial_Coder probably no image on the page ... Use debuger for this questions :)

Comment: @Serial_Coder I add one check about the count of htmlElementsCollection if the count is 0 show Message and return.